# Creating an inventory in excel 2011 for backpacking

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I have an inventory list of backpacking gear in excel 2011, but I would like to be able to select the gear I am actually taking on a trip and have it populate another list. The inventory list has the weight of each item listed in a column and I would like the populated list to have a total weigh. This project would allow me to build my inventory as I purchase more equipment and easily create a packing list for each individual trip. I feel like this should be pretty simple.

Comment: Show us your effort. Add examples. We are not scripting service.

Comment: Add an example of your Data and how the result will be

Answer (score 0):

In your list add a column "Included" to hold e.g. a "Y", "True" or similar when the item on that row is to be included in your calculations.

Select your list, enable the Autofilter; where you find it depends on the Excel version you're running.

Type your choice "selector" in the "Included" column on the items you wish to have included.

Click the heading [v]-button on the "Included"-column to display the menu. In there you may now select to show only your chosen items.

With this in place, use the `SUBTOTAL(...)` function to place sums/counts of the selected items in any cell you wish. Note that the first argument has to be above 100 to count/consider only the VISIBLE items in the Autofilter list.

"Pretty simple"! Happy hacking!

*(Typed from memory, no testing, errors may exist)*